# Updating controlling picklist through data loader or workbench does not respect field dependency

Tags: picklist, field-dependencies

I have field dependency defined for two picklist field

Controlling picklist: field 1 which has picklist Value 1,2
Dependent picklist: field 2 which has picklist Value 3,4

Field dependency 1->3 and 2->4

When updating controlling picklist value through developer console or workbench it allows to save with invalid dependency.

Say record xyz was created with controlling field value set to 1 and Dependent picklist to 3

Updating controlling picklist value via workbench or developer console to 2 with Dependent picklist value still as 3 does not throw any error.

Is this expected behavior in salesforce, if yes do we have any documentation for the same.

Comment: Please edit your question and provide a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0):

The import process/API does not consider dependencies so it is expected. I guess there is no official document supporting the same but in the [Article](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.fields_dependent_field_considerations.htm&type=5) it we have the below for data import wizard

> The Data Import Wizard doesn’t consider field dependencies. You can
> import any value into a dependent picklist regardless of the value
> imported for a controlling field.

Comment: Thanks @Saipraveen.

I read the article before but field dependency is enforced when i do insert or if dependent values are inserted or updated with invalid value.

However only for controlling picklist during update process it does not work.